On the dot product of a vector with a bivector
I have this identity
$$a\cdot (b \wedge c) = (a \cdot b)c - (a \cdot c)b$$

which I can prove pretty straight forward, using that $ X\cdot Y = XY_\parallel$ and $ X \wedge Y = XY_\perp$ (Where I break Y into parts that are parallel and perpendicular to X and are of the same grade as Y) and breaking $b$ and $c$ into parts perpendicular and parallel to $a$

$$a\cdot (b \wedge c) = a\cdot ((b_\parallel + b_\perp) \wedge (c_\parallel + c_\perp)) = a \cdot (b_\parallel \wedge c_\perp + b_\perp \wedge c_\parallel) = a \cdot (b_\parallel c_\perp + b_\perp c_\parallel)$$

(In the 2nd part $b_\parallel \wedge c_\parallel = 0$ and $a \cdot (b_\perp \wedge c_\perp) = 0$ because the latter term is perpendicular to $a$). Also because $a$ is parallel to these bivectors and the very same thecnique works with bivectors-vectors:

$$a \cdot (b_\parallel c_\perp + b_\perp c_\parallel) = a \cdot (b_\parallel c_\perp - c_\parallel b_\perp) = ab_\parallel c_\perp - ac_\parallel b_\perp = (a \cdot b)c - (a \cdot c)b$$
Now I have this other approach where I can determine what the answear should be up to a scalar, but I can't go further:
Intuition of the inner product tells us, that the answear to $a\cdot (b \wedge c)$ lies in the span of $b$ and $c$, since it should be the vector we get if we contract $b\wedge c$ in the direction of $a$ (or at least in $a_\parallel$). That means:
$$a\cdot (b \wedge c) = a_1 b + a_2 c$$
Now we would also expect that the answear is perpendicular to $a$, since $a$ was "contracted" from the bivector. So taking the dotproduct with $a$ on both sides:
$$a \cdot (a\cdot (b \wedge c)) = 0 =  a_1 a\cdot b + a_2 a\cdot c$$
$$a\cdot (b \wedge c) = -a_2 (a\cdot c)/(a\cdot b)b + a_2 c$$
Now if $\alpha = a_2 /(a\cdot b)$:
$$a\cdot (b \wedge c) = \alpha ((a \cdot b)c - (a \cdot c)b)$$
Now this captures the span of the answear, but doesn't tell anything about magnitude and orientation (that is what $\alpha$ regulates)... What am I missing? What property of the inner product am I ignoring, that would tell us what the orientation and magnitude of the answear is?

Your first approach implicitly rewrites the dot products and wedge products in terms of geometric products and uses the associativity of the geometric product.
Your second approach axiomatizes properties of the product $\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c})$ and then looks for a vector that satisfies the properties.
The equation $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}=0$ only tells us that $\vec{x}$ points in one of the directions orthogonal to $\vec{y}$; it does not tell us anything about the magnitude or orientation of $\vec{x}$ along a direction or even the number of possible orthogonal directions. You determined the number of possible orthogonal directions by requiring the product to be in the span of $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$, but you haven't specified the remaining degrees of freedom (orientation and magnitude).
So we just need to add axioms for the orientation and magnitude.

Which space? $\vec{x} \wedge(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c}) = 0$
Which subspace? $\vec{x}\cdot \vec{a}_\parallel = 0$ where $\vec{a}_\parallel=P_\parallel^{\left( \vec{b}\wedge\vec{c}\right)}(\vec{a})$ is the part of $\vec{a}$ which is parallel to $(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c})$.
Which orientation? $\frac{\vec{a}_\parallel\wedge\vec{x}}{\lvert\vec{a}_\parallel\wedge\vec{x}\rvert} = \frac{\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c}}{\lvert\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c}\rvert}$
Which magnitude? I think this comes from the linearity properties of the dot and wedge products and requiring that the dot product of a unit vector in the plane with the unit 2-blade of the plane should give a unit vector.


Thank you! That's really helpful. I especially like your approach to the magnitude part of the problem. However do you think that our choice about the orientation is arbitrary? For example if all the basis square to -1 the orientation changes in the formula.

No, the choice of orientation was not arbitrary. I chose the orientation to be consistent with the first approach. The scale and orientation are already specified in GA by the axioms of the geometric product.
